# Not getting a solution from SolveAlways

Tags: equation-solving

I have the system of equations shown below, but evaluating the `SolveAlways` expression gives `{}`.

```
SolveAlways[
  {x^2 (486.6984230987389` + 119.74403412878252` a) == 0, 
   x (486.69842309873883` + 119.74403412878283` a) == 0, 
   y (486.6984230987389` + 119.74403412878252` a) == 0, 
   486.6984230987388` + 119.74403412878283` a == 0}, 
  {x, y}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it just happens to have an empty solution set.

Answer (score 2):

@Farid, Answer to your comment "complex problem".

Here you also get 3 results with "Solve"

```
sol1 = Solve[{x^6 (108.93871131644518` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^3 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (1310.7946326563795` + 3017.549660045319` c) == 0, 
   x^4 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^2 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0}]

(*  {{x -> 0.}, {a -> 0.131636, b -> -1.17882, 
                 c -> -0.43439}, {a -> -0.0228509 - 0.131053 b, c -> -0.43439, 
      y -> 0.}}    *)
```

The first, x->0. means, y and a,b,c are arbitrary when x==0.

Second means x and y are arbitrary at certain a,b,c

Third means x is arbitrary at definite y,a,b,c

You can get the same with "SolveAlways"

"SolveAlways for all y" gives the first and second solution

```
 sol2 = SolveAlways[{x^6 (108.93871131644518` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^3 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (1310.7946326563795` + 3017.549660045319` c) == 0, 
   x^4 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^2 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0}, y]

(*    {{b -> -1.17882, a -> 0.131636, c -> -0.43439}, {x -> 0.}}   *)
```

"For all x" gives the second and third solution

```
sol3 = SolveAlways[{x^6 (108.93871131644518` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^3 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (1310.7946326563795` + 3017.549660045319` c) == 0, 
   x^4 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^2 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0}, x]

(*    {{a -> -0.0228509 - 0.131053 b, c -> -0.43439, 
        y -> 0.}, {b -> -1.17882, a -> 0.131636, c -> -0.43439}}    *)
```

"For all x and y" gives the second solution

```
sol4 = SolveAlways[{x^6 (108.93871131644518` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^3 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0, 
   x^5 (1310.7946326563795` + 3017.549660045319` c) == 0, 
   x^4 (108.9387113164452` + 4767.373520195115` a + 
   624.7769789615303` b) == 0, 
   x^2 y (1963.9924889298525` + 1666.0719438974168` b) == 0}, {x, y}]

(*   {{b -> -1.17882, a -> 0.131636, c -> -0.43439}}    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of "SolveAlways":

SolveAlways[eqns,vars]
gives the values of parameters that make the equations eqns valid for all values of the variables vars.

That means, equations should be valid for all x,y.
That's not the case.

Use simple "Solve"

```
Solve[{x^2 (486.6984230987389` + 119.74403412878252` a) == 0, 
       x (486.69842309873883` + 119.74403412878283` a) == 0, 
       y (486.6984230987389` + 119.74403412878252` a) == 0, 
          486.6984230987388` + 119.74403412878283` a == 0}]
```

to get

```
 (*   {{a -> -4.06449, x -> 0., y -> 0.}}    *)
```